# nl2br and str_replace not working in PHP script

Tags: php, nl2br

I am saving and editing data in text files through a text area using CKeditor and everything is working smoothly. Everything except new lines ("`<br />`") that don't show when I try to edit/update the text file via my update.php. I really can't find out what is the issue, I have tried to replace tag after tag and did not manage to solve the problem.

Code for reading and writing on the text file:

```
$text1 = "../conteudos/start/text1.txt";
if (isset($_POST['body1'])) {
    $newData = nl2br($_POST['body1']);
    $handle = fopen($text1, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newData);
    fclose($handle);
}
// ------------------------------------------------
if (file_exists($text1)) {

    $myData1 = file_get_contents($text1);
    $myData1 = strip_tags($myData1);
}
```

Code for editing the text contents:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="body1" id="body1">
    <?php echo str_replace("<br />","",$myData1); ?>
</textarea>
```

As mentioned before, the text shows up nicely on my index.php with no html tags whatsoever, but when I try to edit it via the text area above I still get no tags, but I get all the text into one single line. This really should be working because I am using "nl2br" function, but apparently something is canceling it.

What can I do?

Comment: @AmalMurali This has nothing to do with databases...

Comment: @Amal Murali I am using txt files, no databases... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something very strange happened because according to the user Touch, his method was working on his computer. Unfortunately it wasn't working on mine! So after a while thinking I came to the conclusion that I was over doing some process of replacement of tags. In order to confirm or not this theory of mine I decided do "back-engineer" Touch's method by erasing line by line and seeing what the result was. In the end I saw that my conclusion was correct, I was over doing process of tag replacement because this code:

```
$text2 = "../conteudos/start/text2.txt";
if (isset($_POST['body2'])) {
    $newData = nl2br($_POST['body2']);
    $handle = fopen($text2, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newData);
    fclose($handle);
}
// ------------------------------------------------
if (file_exists($text2)) {

    $myData2 = file_get_contents($text2);
    $myData2 =  $myData2;
}
```

worked in perfection. I can only think that this was due to I was using KCEditor...

**A big thanks to all that answered, maing me think and helping me this way to achieve my goal!**

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
$text1 = "../conteudos/start/text1.txt";
if (isset($_POST['body1'])) {
    $newData = nl2br($_POST['body1']);
    $handle = fopen($text1, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newData);
    fclose($handle);
}
// ------------------------------------------------
if (file_exists($text1)) {

    $myData1 = file_get_contents($text1);

    //Change it here first
    str_replace("<br />","\n",$myData1); //You also forgot the new line character I think.

    $myData1 = strip_tags($myData1);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="body1" id="body1">
  <?php echo $myData1; ?>
</textarea>
```

You made a small logic error according to what I see. According to my understanding, you want to strip out the tags but preserve the new line. So change the "< br />" first before you strip out the tags. Hopefully that's what you want I guess.

Comment: If it is correct I am doing something wrong because it is still not working. I am going to go through it some times to try to see what is happening... But YES, that is what I meant! :)

Comment: There is a development though: New lines are now being converted into white spaces...

Comment: @user2598619 Did you use the `str_replace("<br />","\n",$myData1);` exactly as I typed it? And what what do you mean by "There is a development"?

Comment: By "There is a development" I meant that before absolutely nothing was happening and now (after your tip) the new lines are being replaced by spaces. I did copied and pasted you code as it is, didn't change a thing...

Comment: My best guess is that must most probably be some other error. You could have another logic error else where, I tested the line I wrote and it works on my PHP (Ubuntu Linux).

Comment: Ok, so it is deffo something I am doing wrong... I guess that it is best that I stop for today and take a better look tomorrow, usually works! I'll keep on trying!

Comment: Just checked the txt file and this is what it is being written there: &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; - Does it add some new information?

Comment: Nope. It's been escaped. `&lt;br /&gt;` is `<br />` but the browser won't go to a new line with the first one, it will display as you would see it in the second one. You most probably esaped it. Is the code you provided exactly as is in you script?

Answer (score 0):

You are stripping the tags from your file (`$myData1 = strip_tags($myData1)`). `<br />` is a tag, so you're stripping it out too!

This makes your `str_replace` useless, since the tag has already been stripped. In any case, you shouldn't need that `nl2br` in the first place, since newline characters are perfectly valid inside text files...

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that I should delete my str_replace when echoing the txt file on the text area?

Comment: I'm just confused as to what you're doing. Why do you need to use `nl2br` to save in a text file? Why are you stripping out tags instead of using the non-destructive `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: Because maybe I don't know better. That is why I am here seeking help. I don't want any tags - and they are never showing, that's good! When I insert some text on the txt file via edit.php, everything goes correctly, as it should, and and I can see the good result on the index.php. But when I go back to the edit.php, I get all the text on a single line. So all my new lines disappeared... This is not what I want, I want to see the text as it shows on index.php(with the new lines everytime I pressed the Enter key). Is it more clear now?